# VuePress: Trying to find a way to automatically update the sidebar based on folder version naming

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

I am trying to create a documentation site that allows developers to easily version things and not have to manually update the sidebar. For example, I have a version switching pulldown that lets the user select a version. I want the sidebar to reflect the path change so that the user sees documentation for that version and not the `/master/` which is always the latest version.

I am currently using [this approach](https://github.com/avajs/ava/pull/2051) for part of what I'm working on (the version switching and documenting in `releases.json`).

Below is an example of what I have currently. So in order for the developer to create a new version, they would copy the entire `master` directory into something named like `v1.1.5`, make their content changes in the contained markdown files, and then when the user switches versions, the `children` paths would reflect that change.

```
{
  title: 'Getting Started',
  collapsable: true,
  children: [
    '/master/getting-started/concepts',
    '/master/getting-started/technology',
    '/master/getting-started/dependencies',
    '/master/getting-started/architectural-diagrams',
    '/master/getting-started/quickstart'
  ]
},
```

So upon changing to another version via the pulldown menu, it would change an item to something like `/v1.1.5/getting-started/concepts`.

Is there any way to do this in VuePress? I was thinking maybe the version segment of the URL could be saved somewhere, like in Vuex, but I'm not sure of the best approach for that. Even having the URLs be relative instead of absolute to their versions would probably work.

Comment: So I may have a simple solution. Instead of banging my head against the wall trying to figure out something custom, I think I can instead use the [automatic sidebar feature](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/default-theme-config/#auto-sidebar-for-single-pages) and then restructure my markdown files accordingly. I can leverage markdown includes in an effort to break things up and make the content easier to manage.